# Error: The Term "invoke-webrequest" is not recognized

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-functions

when i try to run this code in windows powershell

```
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `
  -Method POST `
  -Headers $headers `
  -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
  -InFile request.json `
  -Uri "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/videos:annotate" | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

I recieve this error:

> The term "Invoke-WebRequest" is not recognized

Comment: Please, Run $PSVersionTable in PowerShell and update your question with that information.

Comment: Te public document "Problems with the Invoke-WebRequest sample" provides you some suggestions: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors?hl=es-419#issues_with_the_example_invoke-webrequest

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-WebRequest was added in powershell 3.0

So your powershell is older. *Windows 7 comes with 2.0 if that is your case.*

You can update it by installing WMF 5.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/setup/install-configure

If you can't update it, you will have to use the Net Framework's class for web requests:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest